# jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax. Как решить?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc, intelij

Есть запрос:

```
 INSERT INTO DocumentWarehouse (`Ref`, `Number`, `DateTime`)
        VALUES
        ('4583b3b4-c53f-11e8-bca5-0025b502b04e', '102-01554356', '2018-10-01T09:00:17')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Ref = VALUES(Ref);
        DELETE FROM DocumentWarehouse_Owner WHERE "Ref" IN
        ("4583b3b4-c53f-11e8-bca5-0025b502b04e");
     INSERT INTO DocumentWarehouse_Owner (`Ref`, `RowNumber`)
        VALUES
        ('4583b3b4-c53f-11e8-bca5-0025b502b04e', '1.0');
```

Выдает ошибку в Intelij Idea:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM DocumentWarehous_OwnerDocuments WHERE "Ref" IN
(' at line 5
```

В консоли выполняется нормально.Что может быть?

P.S:
вот метод генерирующий часть кода на который ругается:

```
private String getDeleteChildRows(EntityModel entityModel, LinkedList<String> refValues) {
        StringBuilder deleteChildFieldRequest = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder deleteChildValues = new StringBuilder();

        for (String value : refValues) {
            deleteChildValues.append(String.format("\"%s\",\n", value));
        }
        deleteChildValues.setLength(deleteChildValues.length() - 2);

        for (String childTableName : entityModel.getTabularSection().keySet()) {
            deleteChildFieldRequest.append(String.format("DELETE FROM %s_%s WHERE \"Ref\" IN\n(%s);\n", entityModel.getName(), childTableName, deleteChildValues));
        }
        return deleteChildFieldRequest.toString();
    }
```

также:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>


 private BasicDataSource ds;
    private static String databaseUrl;
    private static String user;
    private static String password;
    private static int dbPoolSize;

    public DataSource(String databaseUrl, String user, String password, int dbPoolSize) {
        DataSource.databaseUrl = databaseUrl;
        DataSource.user = user;
        DataSource.password = password;
        DataSource.dbPoolSize = dbPoolSize;
        ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setUsername(user);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        ds.setUrl(databaseUrl);
        ds.setMaxIdle(dbPoolSize);
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
        ds.setDefaultTransactionIsolation(TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
        ds.addConnectionProperty("useUnicode", "yes");
        ds.addConnectionProperty("characterEncoding", "utf8");
```

---

```
 private Statement statement;
statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

---

public void executeRequest(String request) throws SQLException {
        statement.execute(request);
}

Comment: Двойные кавычки в `"Ref"` замените на `\`Ref\``

Comment: не помогло, ошибка таже

Comment: как запускаешь запрос? код в студию

Comment: дописал в описание

Comment: Простите, а использованный Вами метод работы с MySQL точно допускает передачу пакета из нескольких запросов?

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский есть предположение, при указании параметра в IN нужно указывать строку в одинарных кавычках, а не в двойных `IN('4583b3b4-c53f-11e8-bca5-0025b502b04e')` вместо `IN ("4583b3b4-c53f-11e8-bca5-0025b502b04e")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать - пропихнуть некий кортеж запросов через один Statement является плохим решением по определению.

У вас не возникнет проблем если вы выполните ваши DML операции по очереди в разных Statement.

Если вы все же точно уверены что хотите пойти извилистой дорогой, то в случае MySql вам нужно включить особую настройку под названием allowMultiQueries. Делается это довольно просто - в настройках соединения с БД дописать этот параметр к URL примерно вот так:

```
String mySqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///example?allowMultiQueries=true";
```

Второй вариант - вы можете создать процедуру с вашим набором запросов и выполнить ее.

Comment: один Statement является плохим решением по определению. - почему? у меня на сомом деле будут идти не по одной записи как здесь, а пачки с INSERT, DELETE...

Comment: Потому что Statement - по определению единичная операция.

Comment: Представьте что вам задали задали вопрос - какого цвета ваша машина и сколько у нее лошадинных сил, а ответ вам нужно дать одним словом. То же самое и здесь - вы получите несколько resultset и метаданных на одно обращение, что конечно же представляет сложность для jdbc драйвера.